# How to remove the Careers 2.0 banner?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Apologies if this has already been asked.
I use StackOverflow a lot at work, and I have many people walking past my screen every day.
Is there any way to remove the Careers 2.0 banners from the site?

I have registered with Careers 2.0 in the hopes that the banners will disappear, but they don't.
I always worry that people think I'm looking for another job all day, when I'm doing important work-related research.

Comment: It's not a dupe, this is about the banner, not the side-ads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!

Earn [200+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads) and the banner will be gone...

Comment: Thank you! Better start asking more questions :-)

Comment: ...Or answering questions.

Comment: I have much more than 200+ reputation, but I still have the Careers 2.0 banner (not talking about the advertisement).

Comment: @crush - Are you talking about [this banner (colored red)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9kupb.png) or [this side ads](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tj9Em.gif)?