# What's the longest question duplicate chain on SE?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, statistics

I wonder what the longest question duplicate chain is on SE. For example, [Matching files with various extensions using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223817/395857) is closed a duplicate of [Brace expansion with variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19432753/395857), which is closed a duplicate of [Variables in bash seq replacement ({1..10})](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6191146/395857) which is closed a duplicate of [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/169511/395857). That's a question duplicate chain length of 3.

Comment: Do duplicates chains that have since been re-opened (and broke the chain) count...? If so, I _may_ have an answer for this

Comment: @cocomac I'm guessing it was broken because of an infinite loop?

Comment: Yep. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169415) or search for "circular duplicates meta stack exchange". If those are fair game, then it'd be infinity most likely. For a proper answer, it's an interesting SEDE SQL question. Not sure about how I'd go about writing SQL to find that, though

Comment: @cocomac Thanks, good point, let's ignore circular duplicates.

Comment: [Here's](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179727/duplicate-chains) a list of some of the weirder ones, though I don't know if any of them is the _longest_. (I once saw an answer by Glorfindel on a since-deleted question that linked an insanely long chain.)

Comment: [A recursive query like this will run](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1790114) on pretty much every site [up to and including Server Fault](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/1790116), but unfortunately won't finish on Stack Overflow before timing out. If that could finish there it could be run network wide....

Comment: Honestly, a search like this might make a good community event...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TLDR; 10 Links<sup>1</sup>** starting from any of:

- https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/455
- https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1892
- https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2159
- [Is it possible to change the "integral-dependance" tag into "integral-dependence"?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16727)

---

### Intro

Honestly, this was really fun to work through. I had to reevaluate quite a lot of assumptions through this process, like all sites have duplicate questions and that every question closed as a duplicate has a dupe target (both of which are incorrect).

#### SEDE

I started out on SEDE and made it through any number of variations which all ultimately did not do what was needed. I couldn't get any query to complete on Stack Overflow and couldn't create a query that would run network-wide. I was only able to pull limited sections of sites before it timed out. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1790136/longest-duplicate-chains-network-wide-attempt) represents one of many many many attempts at solving this problem there and covers less than half of the available sites.

Ultimately, I decided it would be easier to just step away from SEDE and move to the data dumps. I used the 2023-09-12 Stack Exchange Data Dump which is the most current version at this time.

#### Data Dump Process

I pulled down all the data and pulled out just the PostLinks.xml file from every site. I renamed the files so that they follow the format of `{site}-PostLinks.xml` and put them in a folder called "PostLinks." A really great benefit of using the data dumps instead of SQL for this is that I can solve it graphically as longest path problem  instead of using a recursive lookup.

#### Approach

Ultimately, I ended up using [networkx's dag_longest_path](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.dag_longest_path.html) to find the "longest path" per site. Please note, that this function only returns one instance of the longest path so there may be several paths of that length which are not visible here. This was a huge time saver and does fine to answer the question of "What's the longest question duplicate chain on SE?"

### Results

At this time, considering the information available the longest duplicate chain is **10 links**. This occurs on multiple different sites.

See the following summary table of the top 15 values network wide (unfortunately the full result set is 85k characters and won't fit in an answer on SE, one of the main drawbacks of not using SEDE here):

#### Network-wide

| Site Name | Number of links | Link to start | Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple.meta.stackexchange.com | 10 | https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/455 | 455 -> 932 -> 1519 -> 1882 -> 2318 -> 2717 -> 2964 -> 3190 -> 3463 -> 3716 -> 4006 |
| gaming.meta.stackexchange.com | 10 | https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1892 | 1892 -> 3352 -> 5602 -> 8040 -> 10168 -> 11204 -> 12230 -> 12860 -> 13242 -> 14958 -> 15880 |
| drupal.meta.stackexchange.com | 10 | https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2159 | 2159 -> 2737 -> 3146 -> 3351 -> 3569 -> 3686 -> 3741 -> 3786 -> 3861 -> 3872 -> 3906 |
| math.meta.stackexchange.com | 10 | [Is it possible to change the "integral-dependance" tag into "integral-dependence"?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16727) | 16727 -> 12485 -> 19037 -> 22348 -> 25694 -> 27653 -> 29718 -> 31103 -> 32974 -> 34525 -> 35451 |
| rpg.meta.stackexchange.com | 9 | https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1497 | 1497 -> 2723 -> 3222 -> 5288 -> 6024 -> 6717 -> 7721 -> 8737 -> 9802 -> 11612 |
| gis.meta.stackexchange.com | 9 | https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/540 | 540 -> 1968 -> 3460 -> 3881 -> 4133 -> 4453 -> 4805 -> 5013 -> 5156 -> 5287 |
| physics.meta.stackexchange.com | 9 | https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/980 | 980 -> 2810 -> 5263 -> 6388 -> 7426 -> 9554 -> 10394 -> 11001 -> 12737 -> 13630 |
| stackoverflow.com | 8 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/72146651 | 72146651 -> 72145571 -> 72142808 -> 72140680 -> 72128963 -> 72127464 -> 72117405 -> 72113318 -> 72104018 |
| christianity.meta.stackexchange.com | 8 | https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750 | 1750 -> 3296 -> 4313 -> 5856 -> 6225 -> 6476 -> 6644 -> 6871 -> 7086 |
| meta.stackexchange.com | 8* | [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31913) | 31913 -> 53346 -> 74983 -> 93312 -> 114442 -> 132988 -> 162128 -> 195823 -> 210389 |
| meta.stackoverflow.com | 7 | https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350845 | 350845 -> 323253 -> 303472 -> 278434 -> 260070 -> 250977 -> 258610 -> 252133 |
| movies.meta.stackexchange.com | 7 | https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1695 | 1695 -> 1745 -> 2089 -> 2616 -> 4131 -> 4433 -> 4644 -> 4772 |
| softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com | 7 | https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8380 | 8380 -> 8398 -> 8412 -> 8423 -> 8435 -> 8442 -> 8455 -> 8467 |
| chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com | 6 | https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2696 | 2696 -> 3079 -> 3546 -> 4097 -> 4364 -> 4653 -> 5028 |
| unix.stackexchange.com | 5 | https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500560 | 500560 -> 414417 -> 17510 -> 13828 -> 9612 -> 120311 |

You'll likely notice rather quickly looking through these posts that the majority of duplicate chains this long are the result of year-to-year events which were closed as duplicates of the succeeding year and exist on meta sites.

The [one here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31913) is a rather special case because it was migrated to MSO and the duplicate chain continues there. Which makes it technically 11 links (one of which is a migration) and 10 links between duplicate targets (this is the <sup>1</sup> in the TLDR and the asterisk in the table) though it is split between two sites. This approach wouldn't successfully track migrations across network, so it is possible there are longer chains than the above including migrated then closed questions.

#### Main sites only (excluding MSE)

By ignoring meta sites we can mostly exclude these types of year-to-year closures. Here are the top 15 results from main sites (excluding MSE):

| Site Name | Number of links | Link to start | Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stackoverflow.com | 8 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/72146651 | 72146651 -> 72145571 -> 72142808 -> 72140680 -> 72128963 -> 72127464 -> 72117405 -> 72113318 -> 72104018 |
| unix.stackexchange.com | 5 | https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500560 | 500560 -> 414417 -> 17510 -> 13828 -> 9612 -> 120311 |
| math.stackexchange.com | 5 | https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1617654 | 1617654 -> 102107 -> 67068 -> 357063 -> 833451 -> 1490794 |
| workplace.stackexchange.com | 5 | https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/47560 | 47560 -> 47451 -> 34828 -> 23527 -> 9032 -> 5560 |
| softwareengineering.stackexchange.com | 4 | https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/129951 | 129951 -> 125435 -> 66438 -> 135311 -> 6395 |
| security.stackexchange.com | 4 | https://security.stackexchange.com/q/200847 | 200847 -> 130961 -> 121044 -> 107828 -> 25219 |
| scifi.stackexchange.com | 4 | https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/160020 | 160020 -> 153440 -> 150036 -> 54108 -> 2611 |
| raspberrypi.stackexchange.com | 4 | https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/76129 | 76129 -> 74552 -> 73469 -> 55035 -> 8861 |
| ell.stackexchange.com | 4 | https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/178587 | 178587 -> 178501 -> 178230 -> 178487 -> 178246 |
| travel.stackexchange.com | 4 | https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/127025 | 127025 -> 100175 -> 37722 -> 29149 -> 66313 |
| ru.stackoverflow.com | 4 | https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/569802 | 569802 -> 563785 -> 494510 -> 422794 -> 506131 |
| superuser.com | 4 | https://superuser.com/q/564968 | 564968 -> 207606 -> 504847 -> 85083 -> 22064 |
| english.stackexchange.com | 4 | https://english.stackexchange.com/q/260200 | 260200 -> 252217 -> 105116 -> 4700 -> 152 |
| puzzling.stackexchange.com | 4 | https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/66455 | 66455 -> 59281 -> 59199 -> 41421 -> 183 |
| blender.stackexchange.com | 4 | https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/40642 | 40642 -> 19039 -> 15207 -> 7627 -> 1842 |

Again, there may be more than one chain of the same length on the site. This approach only found one instance of the longest path.

---

### Infinite Cycles

While here I also found 103 circular duplicates (since they needed to be removed before finding a "longest path"). Technically all of the following are the longest path with length of infinite.

| Site Name | Link to start | Cycle Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| meta.stackexchange.com | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44774 | 44774 -> 44983 -> 45085 -> 45278 -> 44818 |
| magento.stackexchange.com | https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/126728 | 126728 -> 126655 -> 126645 |
| stackoverflow.com | [How do I redirect back to calling app using ios custom URL scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16580058) | 16580058 -> 16582148 |
| stackoverflow.com | [R Newbie - Histograms/Frequency of values incorporating a quantity Column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23836169) | 23836169 -> 23839177 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/23976362 | 23976362 -> 23975948 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Android 6.0: Get package name of current activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34528283) | 34528283 -> 34506199 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/32939977 | 32939977 -> 32909021 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/31864539 | 31864539 -> 31845093 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/29562920 | 29562920 -> 29564921 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Go: serve static templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27424801) | 27424801 -> 27413997 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Python posting answer from function to entry box in GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26936780) | 26936780 -> 26935846 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26727788) | 26727788 -> 26707733 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Compare two return values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36526872) | 36526872 -> 36526527 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Hash table to getkey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17526151) | 17526151 -> 17526535 |
| stackoverflow.com | [DllImport - An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24297616) | 24297616 -> 24314325 |
| stackoverflow.com | [UNIX script to check if httpd service is on or off and if off send a email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36791290) | 36791290 -> 36791470 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/22840688 | 22840688 -> 22847735 |
| stackoverflow.com | [How to input integer value to an array, based preceeding row + column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21818440) | 21818440 -> 21817821 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Not receiving eMail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20592292) | 20592292 -> 20592116 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/20290648 | 20290648 -> 20290341 |
| stackoverflow.com | [why MyTextView in android isn't aligned to right?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19905275) | 19905275 -> 19904749 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Alternative to using span?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19085080) | 19085080 -> 5137465 |
| stackoverflow.com | [why same code in two technology behaving different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17993032) | 17993032 -> 17993035 |
| stackoverflow.com | [How to change this ajax code to long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15840016) | 15840016 -> 15838715 |
| stackoverflow.com | [How to control the duration of a VideoWriter function in MatLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24761386) | 24761386 -> 24739382 |
| crypto.stackexchange.com | https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15053 | 15053 -> 15054 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Target Smooth Following](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37548099) | 37548099 -> 37551707 |
| stackoverflow.com | [SQL order by date, time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16161627) | 16161627 -> 16163422 |
| blender.stackexchange.com | https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39987 | 39987 -> 39956 |
| ell.stackexchange.com | https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/18904 | 18904 -> 18898 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/4156176 | 4156176 -> 4156249 |
| askubuntu.com | [bought computer with ubuntu program messed up](https://askubuntu.com/q/194357) | 194357 -> 194350 |
| askubuntu.com | [How to get desktop background picture changed periodically?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21787) | 21787 -> 174460 |
| meta.stackexchange.com | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45196 | 45196 -> 45007 |
| raspberrypi.stackexchange.com | https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/22065 | 22065 -> 22061 |
| askubuntu.com | [Why should my business choose Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/100084) | 100084 -> 93142 |
| magento.stackexchange.com | https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/35499 | 35499 -> 35510 |
| math.stackexchange.com | https://math.stackexchange.com/q/601602 | 601602 -> 604492 |
| askubuntu.com | https://askubuntu.com/q/136880 | 136880 -> 137210 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Php sessions switch image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16209881) | 16209881 -> 16208732 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/6642415 | 6642415 -> 6642023 |
| meta.stackexchange.com | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263936 | 263936 -> 263961 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/6871993 | 6871993 -> 6815083 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/924219 | 924219 -> 924222 |
| stackoverflow.com | [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6212629) | 6212629 -> 6213271 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/6071696 | 6071696 -> 6071956 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Question about pointers and strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4380090) | 4380090 -> 12121759 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/5942721 | 5942721 -> 5915159 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/6608586 | 6608586 -> 14186573 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/7840314 | 7840314 -> 3982878 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/5778149 | 5778149 -> 5778167 |
| stackoverflow.com | [get ip address of all connected pc in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5360352) | 5360352 -> 5360497 |
| stackoverflow.com | [can anyone tell me how to use switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5639372) | 5639372 -> 5637799 |
| travel.stackexchange.com | https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/64432 | 64432 -> 64429 |
| superuser.com | [assign router ip address to web server](https://superuser.com/q/201546) | 201546 -> 201550 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/693210 | 693210 -> 464287 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/2793081 | 2793081 -> 2793091 |
| stackoverflow.com | [php - strstr with an ending needle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12050673) | 12050673 -> 3969907 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/616168 | 616168 -> 615843 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/662607 | 662607 -> 661447 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/6577914 | 6577914 -> 6577629 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/790568 | 790568 -> 790533 |
| stackoverflow.com | [User control javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2519251) | 2519251 -> 2602398 |
| stackoverflow.com | [C code compiles as C++, but not as C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3143052) | 3143052 -> 3142420 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/4746634 | 4746634 -> 4746780 |
| stackoverflow.com | [HangMan RandomString Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13818297) | 13818297 -> 13817886 |
| stackoverflow.com | [ereg_replace, preg_replace and PHP 5.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269616) | 6269616 -> 6269693 |
| stackoverflow.com | [height of the dropdown box display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5600982) | 5600982 -> 5600646 |
| stackoverflow.com | [strange behaviour of live wallpaper in preview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12870547) | 12870547 -> 12872613 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/12877232 | 12877232 -> 12878663 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/11674473 | 11674473 -> 11668221 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/11413173 | 11413173 -> 11412839 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/11712020 | 11712020 -> 11712471 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/10737474 | 10737474 -> 10737879 |
| stackoverflow.com | [Finding whether time is in a defined range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10330922) | 10330922 -> 10329134 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/9416521 | 9416521 -> 9415821 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/9075482 | 9075482 -> 9075199 |
| stackoverflow.com | [How can an app detect that it's going to be uninstalled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18692571) | 18692571 -> 3013823 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/7536055 | 7536055 -> 7536087 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/8037684 | 8037684 -> 8012429 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579336 | 6579336 -> 6593441 |
| stackoverflow.com | [In Perl, how can I produce a PDF file using data in an XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7823913) | 7823913 -> 7776629 |
| askubuntu.com | [Desktop launcher documentation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/90345) | 90345 -> 37627 |
| stackoverflow.com | [How would I save a UIButton's properties and load with a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7338218) | 7338218 -> 7336594 |
| stackoverflow.com | [get image height and width in file tag using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6633197) | 6633197 -> 6633190 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/6730757 | 6730757 -> 6731231 |
| meta.stackexchange.com | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44772 | 44772 -> 44790 |
| stackoverflow.com | [How to checkbox id to the modal box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6805540) | 6805540 -> 6805127 |
| meta.stackexchange.com | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28154 | 28154 -> 28126 |
| meta.stackexchange.com | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48307 | 48307 -> 48299 |
| english.stackexchange.com | https://english.stackexchange.com/q/129147 | 129147 -> 129143 |
| chemistry.stackexchange.com | https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/44934 | 44934 -> 44935 |
| math.meta.stackexchange.com | https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19635 | 19635 -> 19636 |
| math.stackexchange.com | https://math.stackexchange.com/q/975148 | 975148 -> 974975 |
| math.stackexchange.com | https://math.stackexchange.com/q/705745 | 705745 -> 705650 |
| electronics.stackexchange.com | https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/95170 | 95170 -> 95043 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/311555 | 311555 -> 385620 |
| wordpress.stackexchange.com | https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/35299 | 35299 -> 35285 |
| tex.stackexchange.com | https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192832 | 192832 -> 192636 |
| superuser.com | [Compress pdf file?](https://superuser.com/q/207606) | 207606 -> 504847 |
| superuser.com | [cannot delete file on windows or mac](https://superuser.com/q/846634) | 846634 -> 846635 |
| superuser.com | [Would an old laptop run with converter SATA to IDE?](https://superuser.com/q/554419) | 554419 -> 554452 |
| superuser.com | https://superuser.com/q/927977 | 927977 -> 927973 |

I also found 17 self duplicates which appear to be a remnant of a very old duplicate closure process wherein the question was just closed because the question already exists but relied on a user to either comment with a link or edit the link into the post themselves. This appears to have been programmatically stored as a self-referencing duplicate link. They all exist on Stack Overflow have been closed for ~14 years.

| Site Name | Link to start | Cycle Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/686052 | 686052 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/351819 | 351819 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/563626 | 563626 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/807502 | 807502 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/389971 | 389971 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/730577 | 730577 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/298164 | 298164 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/887293 | 887293 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/601361 | 601361 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/318242 | 318242 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/156872 | 156872 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/268730 | 268730 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/560291 | 560291 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/450161 | 450161 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/94558 | 94558 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/552256 | 552256 |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/q/151375 | 151375 |

---

Here is the approach I used to find these:

```py
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List, Generator

import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


def make_df_from_xml(fp: Path) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_xml(fp)
    df = df.loc[
        df['LinkTypeId'].eq(3),  # Only care about duplicate link types
        ['PostId', 'RelatedPostId']
    ].copy(deep=True)
    return df


def save_cyclic_deps(dupe_cycles: List[object]) -> None:
    if not dupe_cycles:
        return

    p = Path('./raw_cycle_output.csv')
    if not p.exists():
        pd.DataFrame(dupe_cycles).to_csv(p, index=False)
    else:
        pd.concat([
            pd.read_csv(p),
            pd.DataFrame(dupe_cycles)
        ]).drop_duplicates().sort_values(
            by='Cycle Length',
            ascending=False
        ).to_csv(p, index=False)


def ids_list_to_str(ids: List[int]) -> str:
    return ' -> '.join(map('{:.0f}'.format, ids))


def create_link_to_start(site: str, ids: List[int]) -> str:
    if not ids:
        return ''
    return f'https://{site}/q/{ids[0]}'  # Link to start of path/cycle


def process_individual_site(site_name: str, df: pd.DataFrame) -> List[int]:
    DG: nx.DiGraph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='PostId', target='RelatedPostId', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

    dupe_cycles = []

    # Remove any circular dependencies
    for coord in list(nx.simple_cycles(DG)):
        dupe_cycles.append({
            'Site Name': site_name,
            'Cycle Length': len(coord),  # Technically infinite
            'Link to start': create_link_to_start(site_name, coord),
            'Cycle Path': ids_list_to_str(coord)
        })
        if len(coord) == 1:
            # For Stack Overflow
            # Duplicate closures used to just be "This question already has answers here"
            # and a user would have to manually edit or comment with a link
            # this appears to be stored programmatically as a self cycle
            s, = coord
            DG.remove_edge(s, s)
        else:
            s, *_, e = coord
            # Remove back edge
            DG.remove_edge(e, s)

    save_cyclic_deps(dupe_cycles)

    res = nx.dag_longest_path(DG)
    return res


def get_longest_path_for_all_sites() -> Generator[dict]:
    progress_glob = tqdm(glob(r'.\PostLinks\*-PostLinks.xml'))

    for post_links in progress_glob:
        p = Path(post_links)
        [site, *_] = p.stem.split('-')

        # Update progress with current site
        progress_glob.set_postfix_str(site)

        longest_path = process_individual_site(site, make_df_from_xml(p))

        yield {
            'Site Name': site,
            'Number of links': len(longest_path) - 1,  # Edge count instead of node count
            'Link to start': create_link_to_start(site, longest_path),
            'Path': ids_list_to_str(longest_path)
        }


def main() -> None:
    pd.DataFrame(
        get_longest_path_for_all_sites()
    ).sort_values(
        by='Path Length',
        ascending=False
    ).to_csv('./raw_aggregated_output.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: RE the final section, about questions closed as duplicates without targets: prior to May 20, 2009, the system did not prompt for a target when users voted to close as duplicates, and prior to February 2013, targets weren't saved in the database (then were backfilled using info from the automatic edits). See [this comment thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349996/add-the-duplicate-link-to-the-closed-banner-for-old-duplicates#comment1171636_349996) and its link.

Comment: Regarding some of the infinite loops: I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580058) which is closed as a dupe of another question that seems to have been deleted ...